# Как я могу изменить цвет иконки в TabBar в проекте MAUI

Tags: c#, color, icon, maui

Я вставляю иконку в  она приобретает другой цвет как я могу изменить цвет иконки на оригинальный.
[image: Иконка с рядом с надписью CatsPage.]

Я все перепробовал но ничего не происходит.
На самом деле иконка разноцветная. Иконка вставляется в FlyoutIcon для меню.Тоже самое с нижними иконками. Они тоже на самом деле разноцветные.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предположу что [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74253764/6808809)...?

Comment: Использовал то что там описано с дефолтным значком все работает но когда устанавливаю кастомную иконку то она отображается белого цвета.Иконку устанавливаю так FlyoutIcon="cat.png"

Comment: Скиньте сюда эту `cat.png`. Вообще, когда указывается растровое изображение, оно никак не изменяется, это не вектор. Поэтому у меня предположения, что ваша `cat.png` сама просто имеет белый цвет. Но могу ошибаться, не MAUI разработчик.

Comment: Скинул фотку у нее прозрачный фон указан.Если его не указывать отображается посто белый квадрат.Я пока и сам новичок в maui и только только его учу, но где то слышал о закрашивании но не понял как это делается.